# Will a site URL with repeating keywords get penalized by search engines?

Tags: seo, google-search, penalty

I have an URL structure like the following:

> example.com/**cellphone**/**nokia**/galaxy-5678-**nokia**-**cellphone**-from-abc/

For more example:

> example.com/**cellphone**/**motorolla**/new-**motorolla**-gta800-**cellphone**-from-zxy/

The directory structure is like the cellphone is the main directory of the module and the words like Motorolla and Nokia are subdirectories which are categories and then comes the title of the cellphone.

Here the word cellphone and Nokia in the first link and cellphone and Motorolla in the second link are repeated.

**Is it any kind of keyword stuffing? will it be penalized by Google?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's important to note that there is no official number that is classed as keyword stuffing and every page/site is different. But in your example it's not a matter if its keyword stuffing or not. You should be making your URLs for your visitors and not the search engines.

Your unnecessary repeating the words, words such as 'new' are stop words and you no need to repeat the manufacturer or cellphone since its mentioned before.

```
example.com/cellphone/motorolla/new-motorolla-gta800-cellphone/
```

is exactly the same as:

```
example.com/cellphone/motorolla/gta800/
```

Focus on Keywords and what the page is about. If its a review then you use:

```
example.com/cellphone/motorolla/gta800-review/
```

If its about 10 reasons why the gta800 sucks then you use something like:

```
example.com/cellphone/motorolla/10-reasons-why-not-to-buy-a-gta800/
```

Cater for your audience not the search engines. There is no need to repeat it more than once: it doesn't make it any more important.

Google has many ways of establishing what the page is about, URL is just one indicator of many. As long as you have the main 'KEYWORD' or Keywords you want to rank then the rest don't matter. Use the title, H1 and meta description for more in depth information. Short URLs are preferred, not only because they have higher click rates but also they are better to link.

Answer (score 2):

If you think putting more keywords in URL is a bad idea, it's most likely a bad idea.

For keywords stuffing in URL, Google can apply penalty or not but it's not recommended to repeat keywords in URL. Prefer this kind of URL:

> example.com/cellphone/nokia/galaxy-5678/

or

> example.com/cellphone/motorolla/gta800/

Otherwise, your website structure looks like good.

Answer (score 0):

Not so long ago, Google implemented new  search algorithm. It is called EMD (Exact Match Domain). It means that low quality sites will be penalized for aggressive domains like `buyrealestatecheap.example` or similar.

I would suggest that you not bother with keywords in the URL. Make your URL structure for your visitors, not search engines. The influence of URL structure on rankings is minimal if not just absent. Make your URLs short and informative. This will increase your click through rate from the search results.